# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DateTime'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have an MVC app that displays info from a database. One of these fields is a DateTime and I am getting the error

> "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DateTime'"

but I cannot see where its trying to index it.

I'm relatively new to C# and MVC so I'm hoping I've made a rookie mistake and someone can quickly show me where I have gone wrong.

The code for the DateTime field is:

```
[DisplayName("Booking Time"), Column("bookingTime"), NotNull]
public DateTime BookingTime
{
    get { return Fields.BookingTime[this]; }
    set { Fields.BookingTime[this] = value; }
}
```

The only [] I can find sets the DisplayName etc.

Comment: `Fields.BookingTime` itself must be of type `DateTime`, so of course you can't index it. What happens if you remove `[this]` from the code?

Comment: @Luke did you look at any of the answers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it, I found a reference to the field being an Int64 in a module I did a while ago so forgot it defaults to Int64

Doh!

Answer (score 1):

you code should look like this

```
[DisplayName("Booking Time"), Column("bookingTime"), NotNull]
public DateTime BookingTime
{
    get { return Fields.BookingTime; }
    set { Fields.BookingTime = value; }
}
```

`Fields.BookingTime` appears to be type `DateTime` instead of `DateTime[]` so you can't access it by index

Answer (score 0):

I think your indexing is wrong, `this` keyword refers the object from which you are calling the property, probably your code will be like this

```
[DisplayName("Booking Time"), Column("bookingTime"), NotNull]
public DateTime BookingTime
{
    get { return this.Fields.BookingTime; }
    set { this.Fields.BookingTime = value; }
}
```